# Google Sheets: Highlight Entire Column if all cells equal "Yes"

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has multiple columns that I am marking Yes or No to keep track of certain details for a property.  When all cells in each column are marked as "Yes" I would like to highlight (change the background color) for that entire row.  I created a sample spreadsheet of what I am trying to do.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1icbFXzas-VBnMsu2gjPd9avW0PN9ii3v7jPRMpp3kY4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and posting it in case someone else needs it.  I ended up using this conditional formula:

`=AND(ARRAYFORMULA(A$2={A$3:A$37}))`

It worked for all the columns.  I got lucky, but would love for someone to explain why it works :-)